# How to remove everything after a year date in RegEx?

Tags: regex, text-editing, bulk

So i have this giant text file.
And I'm trying to remove all events after the dates.

Example

```
1900 Sigmund Freud published 'Interpretation of Dreams' marking the beginning of Psychoanalytic Thought.
```

Result :

```
1900
```

// *The document has years from 1550 BCE - 2015*

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It's unclear what should be the result and what's the difference between your two points above. Also, the example has "1900", but in your second point you mention "date".

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to remove all non-digits to remove the events but the events contain numbers. And there is no hook to pick and remove it with everything after.

Comment: @harrymc i edited the post

Comment: You should provide the RegEx you attempted to use. If you have done that then it's not properly formatted and current not visible in the question body.

Comment: Still unclear: is the problem that there is an optional BCE part. More examples needed.

Comment: `cat giant_text_file.txt |grep -Eo '^[0-9]+( BCE)?'`

Comment: Are the dates **allways** at the beginning of the lines?

Comment: @harrymc, no the BCE is not a problem. Just wanted to remove the event (text) after the year (4 digit). I'm not sure what is unclear about that.

Comment: @bitinerant, thanks man. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Toto, yes always at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the year is always on 4 digits at the start of the line, like in your example, then you can capture it with the following regex:

```
^([0-9]{1,4}( BCE)?)
```

Comment: Thank you @Laurent. Worked like a charm!